# Trouble editing ALL files in directory

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript that makes small changes to a large amount of .csv files.  The script below works just as expected, it makes the changes, then moves the file to a different given location, but it only works on 20-40 of the files at a time, not all the files in the folder.  I am really stuck, and have no clue why it wont make the changes to every file in the folder.... any ideas?  Thanks!

```
Dim objFSO, sourceFiles, xl, wb, sht

Set objFSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set sourceFiles = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\SomeLocation").Files

  For each objFile In sourceFiles
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(objFile)
    Set sht = xl.ActiveSheet

    sht.Cells(3,5) = sht.Cells(1,1)

    wb.Save
    wb.Close True
    objFile.Move ("C:\SomeLocation")
  Next

Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: Is it not changing them or not moving them?

Comment: Not changing them, it will change and move like 20-40 of the files, then the program will end, without any errors, but when I go the source folder almost all of them are still there with their original date modified dates.

Comment: Have you tried using a delay after `wb.Close`? Try `WScript.Sleep 2000` to start with. I've run into issues trying to use an Excel workbook too quickly after closing it, almost as if the call is not synchronous. You should be getting errors, though, unless you have `OERN` defined somewhere not shown in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As your move code - here

```
objFile.Move ("C:\SomeLocation")
```

and in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946421/vb-script-will-not-traverse-every-file-in-a-given-folder) (rev 1)

```
objFSO.MoveFile objFile, "C:\Users\xxx\FixedCSVs"
```

is faulty (missing trailing `\`), it may be worth your while to use a test program like

```
Option Explicit

Const csSrc   = "..\data\31007260\src"
Const csDst   = "..\data\31007260\dst"
Const cnFiles = 5
Const cbAll   = False

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If goFS.FolderExists(csSrc) Then goFS.DeleteFolder csSrc
goFS.CreateFolder csSrc
If goFS.FolderExists(csDst) Then goFS.DeleteFolder csDst
goFS.CreateFolder csDst

Dim f
For f = 1 To cnFiles
    goFS.CreateTextFile goFS.BuildPath(csSrc, f & ".txt")
Next

Dim oSrc : Set oSrc = goFS.GetFolder(csSrc).Files
Dim oFile
f = 0
For Each oFile In oSrc
    WScript.Echo f, oFile.Path : f = f + 1
'   If cbAll Or f Mod 2 Then oFile.Move csDst & "\"
    If cbAll Or f Mod 2 Then goFS.MoveFile oFile.Path, csDst & "\"
Next

WScript.Echo "-------------------"

Dim oDst : Set oDst = goFS.GetFolder(csDst).Files
f = 0
For Each oFile In oDst
    WScript.Echo f, oFile.Path : f = f + 1
Next
```

sample output:

```
cscript 31007260.vbs
0 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\src\2.txt
1 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\src\4.txt
2 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\src\3.txt
3 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\src\1.txt
4 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\src\5.txt
-------------------
0 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\dst\2.txt
1 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\dst\3.txt
2 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\29976432\data\31007260\dst\5.txt
```

to see that VBScript has no problem at all to move a large number of files - the files collection is smart enough to handle changes during the loop.

So the culprit is Excel. Even then I would expect some error message. I trust that you really removed the OERN.

If you put your code to automate Excel after the

```
WScript.Echo f, oFile.Path : f = f + 1
```

line, you may find the (first?) file that breaks Excel. Using the task manager to monitor memory use and/or an accumulation of Excel zombi processes is certainly advisable.

Having a counter like `f` could help you to break the script after a small number of files

```
If f > TooMuch Then Exit For
```

That way you can call your script as often as needed until all files are processed.

Comment: That makes more sense with excel being the problem... I will troubleshoot some of those issues, thank you.